# How to prevent sprites to be moved by mouse in Matter.js?

Tags: javascript, matter.js

I am using [Matter.js](http://brm.io/matter-js) to build games. Starting from one of their examples: [Pyramid](http://brm.io/matter-js/demo/#pyramid), I started playing around. The code fro this specific example is as follows:

```
var Example = Example || {};

Example.pyramid = function() {
    var Engine = Matter.Engine,
        Render = Matter.Render,
        Runner = Matter.Runner,
        Composites = Matter.Composites,
        MouseConstraint = Matter.MouseConstraint,
        Mouse = Matter.Mouse,
        World = Matter.World,
        Bodies = Matter.Bodies;

    // create engine
    var engine = Engine.create(),
        world = engine.world;

    // create renderer
    var render = Render.create({
        element: document.body,
        engine: engine,
        options: {
            width: 800,
            height: 600,
            showAngleIndicator: true
        }
    });

    Render.run(render);

    // create runner
    var runner = Runner.create();
    Runner.run(runner, engine);

    // add bodies
    var stack = Composites.pyramid(100, 258, 15, 10, 0, 0, function(x, y) {
        return Bodies.rectangle(x, y, 40, 40);
    });

    World.add(world, [
        stack,
        // walls
        Bodies.rectangle(400, 0, 800, 50, { isStatic: true }),
        Bodies.rectangle(800, 300, 50, 600, { isStatic: true }),
        Bodies.rectangle(0, 300, 50, 600, { isStatic: true }),
        Bodies.rectangle(400, 605, 800, 50, { isStatic: true })
    ]);

    // add mouse control
    var mouse = Mouse.create(render.canvas),
        mouseConstraint = MouseConstraint.create(engine, {
            mouse: mouse,
            constraint: {
                stiffness: 0.2,
                render: {
                    visible: false
                }
            }
        });

    World.add(world, mouseConstraint);

    // keep the mouse in sync with rendering
    render.mouse = mouse;

    // fit the render viewport to the scene
    Render.lookAt(render, {
        min: { x: 0, y: 0 },
        max: { x: 800, y: 600 }
    });

    // context for MatterTools.Demo
    return {
        engine: engine,
        runner: runner,
        render: render,
        canvas: render.canvas,
        stop: function() {
            Matter.Render.stop(render);
            Matter.Runner.stop(runner);
        }
    };
};
```

I am trying to modify the code in order to disallow the sprites in the pyramid to be moved by mouse. The part of code responsible for creating those objects is this:

```
// add bodies
var stack = Composites.pyramid(100, 258, 15, 10, 0, 0, 
  function(x, y) {
    return Bodies.rectangle(x, y, 40, 40);
  });
```

I have tried searching among the options that can be passed to `Bodies.rectangle`, but found nothing.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`collisionFilter`](https://brm.io/matter-js/docs/classes/Body.html#property_collisionFilter) property to do this.

Collision filters use groups, masks and categories to determine which bodies collide. I'll ignore groups in this example. By default, bodies belong to category 1 and have all masked enabled:

```js
const objValsToBase = (o, base) =>
  Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(o)
    .map(([k, v]) => [k, v.toString(base)]));

const circle = Matter.Bodies.circle(200, 100, 50);

// show decimal (base 10)
console.log(circle.collisionFilter);

// show bits (base 2)
console.log(objValsToBase(circle.collisionFilter, 2));

// show hex (base 16)
console.log(objValsToBase(circle.collisionFilter, 16));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.19.0/matter.min.js"></script>
```

To get two bodies to stop colliding, you can set the category on one group to `0b10`, which is `0x2` in hex and 2 in decimal, and set the mask on the other to turn off the 2 bit: `0b01`. `0b01` also disables collisions you might have with other categories which are unused by default but might be used in your code sooner or later, so you might prefer `0xfffffd` since `(0xd).toString(2) => '1101'`.

Below is the pyramid example code modified to disable mouse-pyramid collision. I also ran it through [prettier](https://prettier.io/playground) and added a circle that collides with everything to show that the mouse still works on that:

```js
var Engine = Matter.Engine,
  Render = Matter.Render,
  Runner = Matter.Runner,
  Composites = Matter.Composites,
  MouseConstraint = Matter.MouseConstraint,
  Mouse = Matter.Mouse,
  World = Matter.World,
  Bodies = Matter.Bodies;

// create engine
var engine = Engine.create(),
  world = engine.world;

// create renderer
var render = Render.create({
  element: document.body,
  engine: engine,
  options: {
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    showAngleIndicator: true,
  },
});

Render.run(render);

// create runner
var runner = Runner.create();
Runner.run(runner, engine);

// add bodies
var stack = Composites.pyramid(
  100,
  258,
  15,
  10,
  0,
  0,
  function (x, y) {
    return Bodies.rectangle(x, y, 40, 40, {
      collisionFilter: {mask: 0xfffffd}, // <--
    });
  }
);

World.add(world, [
  stack,
  // walls
  Bodies.circle(200, 100, 50),
  Bodies.rectangle(400, 0, 800, 50, {isStatic: true}),
  Bodies.rectangle(800, 300, 50, 600, {isStatic: true}),
  Bodies.rectangle(0, 300, 50, 600, {isStatic: true}),
  Bodies.rectangle(400, 605, 800, 50, {isStatic: true}),
]);

// add mouse control
var mouse = Mouse.create(render.canvas),
  mouseConstraint = MouseConstraint.create(engine, {
    mouse: mouse,
    collisionFilter: {category: 0b10}, // <--
    constraint: {
      stiffness: 0.2,
      render: {
        visible: false,
      },
    },
  });

World.add(world, mouseConstraint);

// keep the mouse in sync with rendering
render.mouse = mouse;

// fit the render viewport to the scene
Render.lookAt(render, {
  min: {x: 0, y: 0},
  max: {x: 800, y: 600},
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.19.0/matter.min.js"></script>
```

See also:

- [How can I change the collisionFilter of an object so it can no longer interact with MouseConstraint (MatterJS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64772783/how-can-i-change-the-collisionfilter-of-an-object-so-it-can-no-longer-interact-w/73262781#73262781)
- [How to get only a single body to move using Matter-js Mouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73252974/how-to-get-only-a-single-body-to-move-using-matter-js-mouse/73262270#73262270)
- [How to prevent sprites to be moved by mouse in Matter.js? #681](https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/issues/681)