# How can I change the collisionFilter of an object so it can no longer interact with MouseConstraint (MatterJS)

Tags: javascript, matter.js

I am working off the [Slingshot](https://brm.io/matter-js/demo/#slingshot) demo. The problem is that after the rock is fired, it can still be clicked on and dragged around, which I want to disable.

I've added a filter to the rock:

```
var rockOptions = {
  density: 0.004,
  restitution: 0.75,
  collisionFilter: { mask: SOLID, category: NEXTBALL }
};
```

And to the mouseconstraint:

```
var mouse = Mouse.create(render.canvas),
  mouseConstraint = MouseConstraint.create(engine, {
    mouse: mouse,
    collisionFilter: { category: NEXTBALL },
    constraint: {
      stiffness: 0.2,
      render: {
        visible: true
      }
    }
  });
```

And then in the click event I attempt to change that filter, so it should no longer match the mouses category:

```
Events.on(engine, "afterUpdate", function () {
  if (
    mouseConstraint.mouse.button === -1 &&
    (rock.position.x > shootPosition.x + 20 ||
      rock.position.y < shootPosition.y - 20)
  ) {
    Composite.remove(engine.world, elastic);

    rock.collisionFilter = {category: SOLID, mask: SOLID};
  }
});
```

But it still is draggable. I'm guessing the problem is how I'm changing the filter on the rock, but I don't see anything in the docs to suggest a way to change it.

I don't think it's because of the categories I've set up, but here they are just in case (the solid and image ones do work, the ball doesn't collide with image ones:

```
const SOLID = 0x0001;
const IMAGE = 0x0002;
const NEXTBALL = 0x0003;
```

Help me make the rock stop being clickable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out after much starting over, tweaking and examining different demos.

First the bitmasks for the categories have to be powers of two, so `NEXTBALL` has to be `0x0004` rather than `0x0003`.

Next, you can't set the whole `collisionFilter` object on an established body, or it breaks the collisions. Instead, you have to use `rock.collisionFilter.category = NEXTBALL`;

Answer (score 2):

Preventing the mouse from manipulating already-shot rocks can be achieved with two simple changes denoted by  `// <---` in the code snippet below.

- `rock.collisionFilter.category = 0b10;` sets the category to 2 for any rock that was just launched, before creating a new one and overwriting the `rock` variable with the next rock to be launched.
- `collisionFilter: {mask: 0b1},` sets the mask on the mouse constraint to only interact with bodies in category 1. Since disabled rocks are in category 2 (`0b10`), the mouse will no longer interact with them.

Here's the code in context. I used [this commit](https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/blob/a3f298fedb34f270e53a6981d25447052c8a8fab/examples/slingshot.js) in case anything changes.

```
Events.on(engine, 'afterUpdate', function() {
  if (mouseConstraint.mouse.button === -1 && (rock.position.x > 190 || rock.position.y < 430)) {
    rock.collisionFilter.category = 0b10; // <---
    rock = Bodies.polygon(170, 450, 7, 20, rockOptions);
    Composite.add(engine.world, rock);
    elastic.bodyB = rock;
  }
});

// add mouse control
var mouse = Mouse.create(render.canvas),
  mouseConstraint = MouseConstraint.create(engine, {
    mouse: mouse,
    collisionFilter: {mask: 0b1}, // <---
    constraint: {
      stiffness: 0.2,
      render: {
        visible: false
      }
    }
  });
```

The default `mask` value is 32 bits all set, or `4294967295`/`0xffffffff`. You may wish to be more precise and disable only the second bit on the mouse constraint: `0xfffffffd`. This lets the mouse interact with anything but category 2 rather than just category 1.

The [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64774265/6243352) is correct that categories should be powers of two so that only one bit is set per category.

The reason `rock.collisionFilter = {category: SOLID, mask: SOLID};` doesn't work is because it destroys the `group` property.

See also:

- [How to get only a single body to move using Matter-js Mouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73252974/how-to-get-only-a-single-body-to-move-using-matter-js-mouse/73262270#73262270).
- [How to prevent sprites to be moved by mouse in Matter.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52914820/how-to-prevent-sprites-to-be-moved-by-mouse-in-matter-js/74909283#74909283)